# Кнопка "Игнорировать" выходит за рамки всплывающего окна с информацией о метке

Tags: дефект, дизайн

С метками уже, видимо, что-то начали делать, но, всё же, некоторые так и не влазят (совсем чуть-чуть):

[image: Кнопка "Игнорировать" выходит за рамки всплывающего окна]

Comment: Судя по всему, [не в приоритете](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/344967/260198) (:

Comment: @Suvitruf-AndreiApanasik, ясно)) заняты темной темой https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/03/31/building-dark-mode-on-stack-overflow/, а то что горизонтальный скролл на странице профиля и не влазят метки это ерунда)

Comment: Может у них там фронтендом один человек занимается)

Comment: @Suvitruf-AndreiApanasik, и тот на карантине)

Comment: @Suvitruf-AndreiApanasik, мне, возможно, кажется, но кнопка уже меньше вылазит за край. Я так думаю, что уже что-то пытались поправить, но не все получилось)

Comment: Ещё несколько попыток и получится. Я в них верю :D

Comment: @Suvitruf-AndreiApanasik, нашла отличие, убрали слово "метку". Было "игнорировать метку", теперь просто "игнорировать" .... можно еще проще - "игнор" )

Comment: Это уже кто-то из переводчиков балуется с локализацией.

Comment: @Suvitruf-AndreiApanasik интересно, кто утверждает. Если в левой кнопке тоже убрать «метку», то влезет. Наверное, КМ всё же иногда просыпается ночью и правит.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ а ты знаешь, как теперь посмотреть автора правки локальки? В Традусёра этого нету. А в трансификс все локальки попадают от имени традусёра.

Comment: @Suvitruf-AndreiApanasik теперь вроде как нельзя. Или хз где спрятано. Можно попробовать традусёро-разрабов спросить.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ [инфа есть](https://github.com/g3rv4/Traducir/issues/134), просто в интерфейсе не светится.